# Merging Columns - Run-time Error 1004: Power Query Macro

Tags: excel, powerquery, vba

Hoping you can help solve a problem that has melted my brains for the past number of days.

I'm new to marcos and Excel Power Query in particular, I am trying to merge a number of non adjoining columns in a workbook and was able to do this successfully in Power Query. My aim is to automate this as much as possible so I decided to record a macro.

When running the recorded macro however I am getting Run-time Error 1004.

My Macro code is as follows:

```
    Sub PQ_CSATMerge()
'
' PQ_CSATMerge Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

> ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$CS$816"), ,
>   xlYes).Name = _
>               "Table3"

```
    Range("Table3[#All]").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table3", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Table3""]}[Content]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type any}, {""Start (UTC)"", type datetime}, {""Visitor ID"", type text}, {""Visitor Name"", type text}, {""MCS"", Int64.Type}, {""Skill"", type text}, {""Agent Name"", type text}, {""Agent Login Name"", type text}, {""Agen" & _
        "t Full Name"", type text}, {""Agent Group"", type text}, {""Chat Start Reason"", type text}, {""Chat End Reason"", type text}, {""Chat Requested Time (UTC)"", type datetime}, {""Length (seconds)"", Int64.Type}, {""Interactive"", type logical}, {""Engagement ID"", Int64.Type}, {""Goal"", type text}, {""Campaign"", type text}, {""Target Audience"", type text}, {""Enga" & _
        "gement Name"", type text}, {""Visitor Behavior"", type text}, {""Country"", type text}, {""State"", type text}, {""City"", type text}, {""ISP"", type text}, {""Organization"", type text}, {""IP Address"", type text}, {""Device"", type text}, {""Browser"", type text}, {""Operating System"", type text}, {""Chat Start Page"", type text}, {""Chat Start URL"", type text}" & _
        ", {""Transcript"", type text}, {""Personal Info Exists"", type logical}, {""Customer Info Exists"", type logical}, {""Marketing Source Exists"", type logical}, {""Lead Exists"", type logical}, {""Lead - Topic"", type text}, {""Visitor Error Exists"", type logical}, {""Service Activity Exists"", type logical}, {""Viewed Product Exists"", type logical}, {""Viewed Prod" & _
        "uct - Products"", type any}, {""Transaction Exists"", type logical}, {""Transaction - Total"", type any}, {""Transaction - Order ID"", type any}, {""Cart Update Exists"", type logical}, {""Cart Update - Total"", Int64.Type}, {""Cart Update - Number of Items"", Int64.Type}, {""Cart Update - Products"", type any}, {""Pre-Chat Survey Exists"", type logical}, {""Post-Ch" & _
        "at Survey Exists"", type logical}, {""Agent Survey Exists"", type logical}, {""Chat Data Enriched"", type logical}, {""Line of Business"", type text}, {""Search Content Exists"", type logical}, {""CoBrowse - Num Sessions"", Int64.Type}, {""CoBrowse - Num Interactive Sessions"", Int64.Type}, {""Alerted MCS"", Int64.Type}, {""Chat MCS"", Int64.Type}, {""Exit Survey - " & _
        "France - Exit Survey - Voulez-vous recevoir une transcription de ce chat?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - France - Exit Survey - Adresse e-mail"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - France - Exit Survey - L'agent du chat était-il capable de résoudre votre requête ou de vous diriger vers une personne capable de vous aider ?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - France - Exit Sur" & _
        "vey - Quelle est la probabilité de recommander SAS à un ami ou à un collègue?"", type any}, {""French_CSAT"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - France - Exit Survey - Dans l'ensemble, était-il facile d'obtenir l'information ou l'aide dont vous avez eu besoin aujourd'hui?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - France - Exit Survey - Veuillez nous faire part de vos commentaires o" & _
        "u suggestions sur la meilleure façon de vous servir"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Italy - Exit Survey - Desidera ricevere per email una copia della chat?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Italy - Exit Survey - Se sì, la preghiamo di fornire la sua email:"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Italy - Exit Survey - Raccomanderebbe SAS ad un amico o un collega?"", type any}," & _
        " {""Italian_CSAT"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Italy - Exit Survey - Nel complesso, quanto è stato facile ottenere le informazioni o l’aiuto di cui aveva bisogno oggi?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Italy - Exit Survey - La preghiamo di fornire dei suggerimenti al fine di poter migliorare il nostro servizio:"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Netherlands - Exit Surv" & _
        "ey - Wilt u dat wij u een kopie van deze chat emailen?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Netherlands - Exit Survey - Email adres"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Netherlands - Exit Survey - Was de chatagent in staat om uw vraag op te lossen of u te leiden naar iemand die kan helpen?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Netherlands - Exit Survey - Hoe waarschijnlijk zou u SA" & _
        "S aan een vriend of collega aanbevelen?"", Int64.Type}, {""Dutch_CSAT"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Netherlands - Exit Survey - Hoe makkelijk was het om de informatie of hulp die u nodig had vandaag te verkrijgen?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Netherlands - Exit Survey - Geef ons alstublieft feedback of suggesties over hoe we u beter kunnen bedienen. "", type te" & _
        "xt}, {""Exit Survey - SAS Exit Survey - English - Would you like us to email you a transcript of this chat?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - SAS Exit Survey - English - Email Address"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - SAS Exit Survey - English - Was the chat representative able to resolve your inquiry or direct you to someone#(cr)#(lf)who could help?"", type text}, {""E" & _
        "nglish_CSAT"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - SAS Exit Survey - English - How likely would you be to recommend SAS to a friend or colleague?"", type any}, {""Exit Survey - SAS Exit Survey - English - Overall, how easy was it to get the information or help you needed today?"", type any}, {""Exit Survey - SAS Exit Survey - English - Please provide us with any feedback o" & _
        "r suggestions for how we can serve you better."", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Spain - Exit Survey - ¿Le gustaría que le enviemos por correo email una copia de este chat?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Spain - Exit Survey - Email"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Spain - Exit Survey - El agente del chat fue capaz de resolver tu consulta o dirigirte a alguien que podr" & _
        "ía ayudarte?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Spain - Exit Survey - ¿Qué probabilidad hay que le recomiende SAS a un amigo o compañero?"", type text}, {""Spanish_CSAT"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Spain - Exit Survey - En general, con que facilidad ha recibido la información o ayuda que necesitaba hoy?"", type text}, {""Exit Survey - Spain - Exit Survey - Por favor" & _
        ", facilítanos cualquier comentario o sugerencia sobre cómo podemos mejorar el servicio."", type any}, {""Chat Operator Survey - SAS Operator Survey - English - What was the nature of the chat?"", type text}, {""Chat Operator Survey - SAS Operator Survey - English - Referred or Resolved?"", type text}, {""Chat Operator Survey - SAS Operator Survey - English - Area""," & _
        " type text}, {""Chat Operator Survey - SAS Operator Survey - English - If further explanation needed, please provide here:"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Merged Columns"" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Changed Type"", {{""Column1"", type text}}, ""en-GB""),{""Column1"", ""French_CSAT"", ""Italian_CSAT"", ""Dutch_CSAT"", ""English_CSAT"", ""Spanish_CS" & _
        "AT""},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("""", QuoteStyle.None),""Merged CSAT"")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Merged Columns"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table3;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table3]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table3_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How about you make life easier by telling us which line errors?

Comment: This line was highlighted in the debugger: ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$CS$816"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table3"

Comment: Also I noticed on previous occasions the last line of code was also highlighted as an error: .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False